# After restarting laptop all files gone

Tags: 20.04, reboot, restore, data-loss

I am using 20.04 version. When I restarted my laptop, all of my files were gone. It is like a fresh Ubuntu install on my laptop. The strange thing is that I can see some apps which I installed before. My personal files are gone! Can you please help me with this situation. How can I get my files back ?

Comment: Are you sure you installed it? and aren't using a *live* system which acts like new computer each time it's launched?   A lot of users write an *live* system to media & consider it installed, but it's not installed unless the installer wrote it.  The next thing to check is you actually removed the installation media (ie. you haven't accidentally re-started the *try* session)

Comment: How can I check that I am using a live system? I am new and I do not know understand your statement exactly

Comment: What is actually a live system?

Comment: A "Live" system means the "Try Ubuntu" environment of the Ubuntu installer. That environment is read-only, so any files created won't be saved. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398227/edit) to clearly list the "*apps which I installed before*". Details help to make your question answerable.